# Ubuntu 12.04 virtual host domain enabled, but not accessible

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-12.04, virtualhost

This is my first attempt at setting up virtual hosts in Apache. I am trying to set up the subdomain `test.mysite.com` for `mysite.com`.

My VPS had Apache already installed on it. In `/var/www`there was an `index.html` file live and running. What I have done since is:

1. Created `/var/www/main/` which is now the default document root,
2. Created `/var/www/test/` which is the content to be served by my virtual host,
3. Copied `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` to `etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.com`.
4. Run `a2ensite test.mysite.com` with a successful message that the site is enabled,
5. Run `service apache2 reload` to reload the server.

These are the first lines that I have modified in `etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ...
```

According to all the guides and tutorials I have found, the subdomain should now be up and running. But my browser can't find the page. Is there anything else I need to do to get my subsite up and running?

Comment: Do you have line NameVirtualHost *:80 before that virtualhost? if not try adding it before that virtualhost definition.

Comment: if this is on public server you should also enable that subdomain from DNS to point that server ip.

Comment: Thanks! I added the line `[IP-adress]:80` before the virtualhost and in the opening tag `<VirtualHost [IP-adress]:80>` since using the * symbol didn't work. Although, this takes me straight to the subdomain when I browse to mysite.com. Not a 100% sure what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer below.. * doesn't work if you don't add/enable that line. After that **<VirtualHost *:80>** should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check you have line (uncommented = not # front):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

in file /etc/apache2/ports.conf

2) check you have A record with your subdomain name in DNS pointing to your server IP.

Comment: I added the subdomain at my hosting provider's website. The file /etc/apache2/ports.conf already had that line in there. When I reload apache, I get this error: `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`.

Comment: Sorry, there was just a delay. It's working now. Thanks a lot!